# How to migrate and insert values in one class and migration in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my migration file:

```php
public function up() {
    $this->execute('
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ad_court` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;');

    $this->insert('ad_court',array(
        'name' =>'Хўжалик суди',
    ));
    $this->insert('ad_court',array(
        'name' =>'Фуқаролик суди',
    ));
}
```

But, when I migrate it is showing error message:

```
 insert into ad_court ...exception 'CDbException' with message
      'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL
 statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
 1146 Table 'chamber_local_site.ad_court' doesn't exist.
```

I need to create a new table and insert values inside it. How can I do it in one migration class?

Answer (score 1):

As user [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration) there is that code,you may use this:

```
class m101129_185401_create_news_table extends CDbMigration {
    public function up() {
        $this -> createTable('tbl_news', array(
                'id' => 'pk',
                'title' => 'string NOT NULL',
                'content' => 'text',
            ));
    }

    public function down() {
        $this -> dropTable('tbl_news');
    }
}
```

Comment: I created migration code.But, I need to create table and insert valuesinside it. In my example, if I remove values(for inserting into the table), it will work. In other cases, it will not work

Comment: Is the table created?The error says, it  is not exist,if not exist why not using $this->createTable,that is my point

Comment: Check also this (it does not say the version of yii but it seems yii1) http://codingtip.blogspot.gr/2013/08/yii-migration-insert-data-to-table.html

Comment: I found answer. I made mistake at implimenting signs('').